# Boostrap markup in Magento blocks and pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento

I am new to working in the Magento CMS. I have a grasp on the creation of blocks and widgets and inserting that content into pages. We are currently using the Bootstrap-based Ultimo theme by Infortis.

How can I use Bootstrap syntax inside of blocks? The basic grid works, but no other classes (alerts, buttons, panels, collapse, etc...) work. I used the Bootstrap CSS/JS CDN and that fixed the classes I just mentioned, but destroyed the theme. I've seen where some extensive jQuery was written to accomplish things like accordions, but that is not in the budget, nor is it at the forefront of my skillset.

Has someone found a workaround for this? Am I missing something?

The only mention of Bootstrap markup in the user guide for this theme is an incredibly brief look at the grid system - A little over 2 pages out of 220.

TL;DR: I'm just trying to use Bootstrap markup inside Magento blocks and the result is making my life difficult.

Comment: Please show your code and say exactly what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the Bootstrap CSS/JS CDN and that fixed the classes I just mentioned, but destroyed the theme

That sounds like Bootstrap classes overriding those of your theme.
Take a look at the source and make sure you're loading in the bootstrap css CDN link *before* your theme's stylesheet. This should prevent any of your theme's styles from being overwritten by Bootstrap's.

After this, if there are still styling conflicts then it might be a case of picking through the site with your browser's element inspector and adding some '!important' properties to any of your theme/custom styles that Bootstrap is causing problems with.

I've developed numerous Magento sites using Bootstrap and can attest to the fact that it's absolutely possible.

If you want more in depth help, you'll really need to post some code for us to look at.